# Fix `useDispatch` in React Redux Monorepo

Tags: redux, next.js, react-redux, monorepo

I have made a Next.JS typescript monorepo [here](https://github.com/hali241997/jest-rollup-issue) with the following folder structure:

```
.
└── packages
    ├── package.json // Housing the monorepo workspace
    ├── web-app // Housing the NextJS website
    └── web-core // Housing the redux business logic
```

Whenever I run yarn dev inside the root or inside the web-app, I get the following parsing error:

```
error - Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
    at useReduxContext (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/packages/web-app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useReduxContext.js:30:11)
    at useStore (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/packages/web-app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useStore.js:28:28)
    at useDispatch (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/packages/web-app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useDispatch.js:24:17)
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:21:78)
    at processChild (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3353:14)
    at resolve (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at Object.renderToString (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at Object.renderPage (/Users/hasnainali/Downloads/Projects/Web/jest-rollup-issue/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:680:46) {
  page: '/'
}
```

[image]

I am doing something wrong with the setup of the monorepo which I am failing to understand. Please help!

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code as text directly to the question, and [format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).